# What is the down migration for adding a polymorphic reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have the folowing migration but don't know what to use in the `down` method

```
change_table :addresses do |t|
  t.references :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the problem?

```
def self.down
  remove_column :addresses, :addressable_type
  remove_column :addresses, :addressable_id
end
```

Comment: are you saying remove_column :addresses, :addressable is not correct?

Comment: Damian: no, just look at the table via some SQL browser and you will see the two columns.

Answer (score 16):

actually,

```
   change_table :addresses do |t|
     t.remove_references :addressable
   end
```

would be a bit railsier, no?

*edit*: As Eben Geer points out

```
   change_table :addresses do |t|
     t.remove_references :addressable, :polymorphic => true
   end
```

is the correct way to do this. Cheers!

Comment: this will cause the addressable_type column to be left behind. it should be t.remove_references :addressable, :polymorphic => true

Comment: I would upvote this answer if it included @EbenGeer his comment

Answer (score 10):

```
class RemoveAddressableFromAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_reference :addresses, :addressable, polymorphic: true, index: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Please take a minute to explain what your code does and how it answers this question.

Comment: This should now be the correct answer: remove_reference can nowadays (since Rails 4.2 at least) be rolled back. That means, Rails knows how to roll back a remove_reference by a add_reference. So this code can be rolled back (though data may by lost in the migration)

Answer (score 7):

```
def self.down
  change_table :addresses do |t|
    t.remove_references :addressable, :polymorphic => true
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

What's wrong with this?

```
def self.down
  remove_column :addresses, :addressable
end
```

Comment: Thats what I thought it would be but this is the first time i have used polymorphic models and got confused

Comment: actually it shouldn't it be  

remove_column :addresses, :addressable

Comment: Oops, you're totally right. I should have checked the docs first, instead of going by memory.