# how to generate migration to make references polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, rails-migrations

I have a Products table and want to add a column:

```
t.references :imageable, :polymorphic => true
```

I was trying to generate migration for this by doing:

```
$ rails generate migration AddImageableToProducts imageable:references:polymorphic
```

but I am obviously doing it wrong. Can anybody make any suggestion? Thanks

When I try to manually put it in after generating the migration, I did it like this:

```
class AddImageableToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :products, :imageable, :references, :polymorphic => true
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :products, :imageable
  end
end
```

and it still hasn't worked

Comment: Not an answer, but to avoid confusion, are you sure you want this column on Products? The rails guide even has a Products example and the column is on Pictures http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: This can be handy: `:references{polymorphic}`. For example, `rails generate migration AddImageableToProducts imageable:references:{polymorphic}`. [Source](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/kaawvv04xh-generate-a-migration-with-polymorphic-association)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Before Rails 4 there was no built-in generator for polymorphic associations. If you are using an early version of Rails generate a blank migration and then modify it by hand according to your needs.

**Update**:
You'll need to specify which table you're changing. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512175/what-is-the-down-migration-for-adding-a-polymorphic-reference/1513396#1513396):

```
class AddImageableToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_table :products do |t|
      t.references :imageable, polymorphic: true
    end
  end

  def down
    change_table :products do |t|
      t.remove_references :imageable, polymorphic: true
    end
  end
end
```

Rails 4 added a generator for polymorphic associations (see simon-olivier answer)

Comment: Thank you very much Brandon. I was able to run the migration. I was wondering though, after you make :polymorphic => true and you open schema.rb are you supposed to see it in the schema as well?

Comment: After you run the migration, `schema.rb` should be updated, but it won't say anything about `polymorphic`. Instead, you should see the actual fields that Rails uses (the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) have more info).

Comment: How do you add index to the `references` column? Do I need to index that?

Comment: @mrudult If I'm not mistaken, you do need to add them yourselves if you need them. You can just add indexes as normal in the migration file to `imageable_type` and/or `imageable_id` as necessary.

Comment: Well if I try `add_index :products, :imageable, unique: true ` It throws `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "imageable" does not exist`. I think I need to manually add indexes for the two columns which are generated. Trying that.

Comment: Yup. adding index to `imageable_id` and `imageable_type` worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should also index this as well: `t.references :imageable, polymorphic: true, index: true`

Answer (score 318):

What you are trying to do is not yet implemented in the stable version of rails so Michelle's answer is the right one for now. But this feature will be implemented in rails 4 and is already available in the edge version as follows (according to this [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d79ca9288e5c55563a554d05c779a41e701181cd)):

```
$ rails generate migration AddImageableToProducts imageable:references{polymorphic}
```

Some shells may need `{polymorphic}` escaped with a `\`:

```
$ rails generate migration AddImageableToProducts imageable:references\{polymorphic\}
```

Comment: Tried this on 4.2, and I'm not sure if this is a bug, zsh, or something else, but the commandline was interpretted as a series of references (as types) with each letter of polymorphic, like: t.referencesp :imagable, treferenceso :imagable, etc.

Comment: @OzBarry, in zsh you'd need to escape the braces: $ rails generate migration AddImageableToProducts imageable:references\{polymorphic\}

Comment: For anyone curious, this generates a migration with change method containing: `add_reference :products, :imageable, polymorphic: true, index: true`

Comment: Incase anyone trying to use the same in scaffold, this works with scaffold as well. Thanks! rijks

Comment: `{polymorphic}` needs to be escaped with the fish shell, e.g. `\{polymorphic\}
`

Answer (score 49):

You could also do the following:

```
class AddImageableToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :products, :imageable, polymorphic: true, index: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 20):

You can try `rails generate migration AddImageableToProducts imageable:references{polymorphic}`

Comment: `{` and `}` need to be escaped with the fish shell at least, e.g. `\{polymorphic\}`

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation about this: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#passing-modifiers

Comment: Thanks Giovanni, that is very useful.